# when i try to update form in django getting this type issue

Tags: javascript, php, python, django

i stored this type value in DB :

**INPUT:**

```
{
    "PatientProfile__is_recruiter": "1", 
    "PatientProfile__partner": "FMCS", 
    "PatientProfile__health_insurance_provider": "MILITARY/VA", 
    "PatientProfile__has_medical_home": "0", 
    "PatientProfile__medical_history_heart_disease": "0", 
    "PatientProfile__medical_history_hypertension": "0", 
    "data_model_name": [
        "PatientProfile"
    ]
}
```

When i try to update   and after updating i found same result like :

```
{
    "PatientProfile__is_recruiter": "1", 
    "PatientProfile__partner": "FMCS", 
    "PatientProfile__health_insurance_provider": "MILITARY/VA", 
    "PatientProfile__has_medical_home": "0", 
    "PatientProfile__medical_history_heart_disease": "0", 
    "PatientProfile__medical_history_hypertension": "0", 
    "data_model_name": [
        "PatientProfile"
    ]
}
```

**if i not update this code and fetch to db and try to execute. i am not getting any error.
when i try to execute this code after updating. i am getting below define error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/accounts/decorators.py", line 44, in inner_decorator
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/reports/views.py", line 97, in hiv_report_new
    return form.get_itable(pk)

  File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/project_name/../project_name/apps/reports/forms.py", line 454, in get_itable
    custom_data =  ast.literal_eval(report_qs[0]['query'])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1

    {


^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Adding random Javascript and PHP tags won't help get your question answered if it's purely about Python, which it is. In any case, you'll certainly need to show the part of forms.py which is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `json` to store `dict` or `list` in `db`

for e.g.

while storing

```
obj = json.dumps("{
    'PatientProfile__is_recruiter': '1', 
    'PatientProfile__partner': 'FMCS', 
    'PatientProfile__health_insurance_provider': 'MILITARY/VA', 
    'PatientProfile__has_medical_home': '0', 
    'PatientProfile__medical_history_heart_disease': '0', 
    'PatientProfile__medical_history_hypertension': '0', 
    'data_model_name': [
        'PatientProfile'
    ]
}")
```

and store json obj i.e obj

and while retrieving use

```
json.loads
```

So you will get as it is, which you saved previously in db..

:)

Answer (score 0):

Use json.dumps while storing :

```
obj = json.dumps("{
'PatientProfile__is_recruiter': '1', 
'PatientProfile__partner': 'FMCS', 
'PatientProfile__health_insurance_provider': 'MILITARY/VA', 
'PatientProfile__has_medical_home': '0', 
'PatientProfile__medical_history_heart_disease': '0', 
'PatientProfile__medical_history_hypertension': '0', 
'data_model_name': ['PatientProfile']
}")
```

While retrieving you have two options i.e;

Example:

```
>>>simplejson.loads('{"x":"y"}') 
{'x': 'y'}


>>> json.loads('{"x":"y"}') 
{u'x': u'y'}
```

i.e. simplejson returns bytestrings if the string is ASCII (it returns 
unicode objects otherwise), while json returns unicode objects always.